# What will be the best practice to wait for a HTTP response in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using HTTPARTY gem to play with HTTP requests and response.
My client is using a authentication agent called Freja eID, after sending the request to them, I have keep poling for there response for 2 minutes.

This is what I did

```
# 2) get Auth Request
  1.upto(24) do |n|
    response = user.getOneAuthResultReuqest(authRef)
    response_status = response['status']
    if response_status == "APPROVED"
      @response_status = response_status
      break
    elsif response_status == "CANCELED"
      @response_status = response_status
      break
    elsif response_status == "EXPIRED"
      @response_status = response_status
      break
    elsif response_status == "FAILED"
      @response_status = response_status
      break
    end
    sleep 5
  end
```

This getOneAuthResultReuqest() will call the method in user model and staright to the another method I created to access Freja APIs.

```
  # Get the result by sending the authRef
  def getOneAuthResultReuqest(authRef)
    data = {authRef: authRef}
    enc_data = Base64.urlsafe_encode64(data.to_json)

    response = JSON.parse(self.class.post("/users/1.0/getOneAuthResult", body: {getOneAuthResultRequest: enc_data}).response.body
  end
```

So here, I just used a loop sleeping for 5 seconds to wait for 2 minutes.
I don't think it is a good approach,

Please help me to figure the best practice for this.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ the whole `if` could be replaced with `@response_status = response_status if %w|APPROVED CANCELED EXPIRED FAILED|.include?(response_status)`.

Comment: Great! Thank you !

Comment: What don't you like about this approach?

Comment: I don't like the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do this kind task is to use the client side.
I thought of doing the process through client side.

```
function GetAuthResult(authRef, user_login, remember_me){
  var closeInSeconds = 120,
  displayText = "Du har 2 minuter att logga in tills sessionen löperut",
 timer;

swal({
 title: "Öppna Freja eID-appen",
 text: displayText,
 timer: closeInSeconds * 1000,
 showConfirmButton: false
});

timer = setInterval(function() {
 closeInSeconds--;

 if (closeInSeconds < 0) {
     clearInterval(timer);
     swal ( "Hoppsan!" ,  "Din inloggningstid har löpt ut!" ,  "error" );
 }

 $.ajax("/api/v3/request_auth_result", {
     type: "POST",
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {
       authRef: authRef
     },
```